# MEGAsync no se ejecuta en Archlinux

Tags: linux, archlinux

estoy utilizando archlinux, e instalado MEGAsync siguiendo los pasos de la página oficial de MEGA, pero cuando ejecuto el programa no me aparece nada.Alguien de la comunidad si tiene MEGAsync en su archlinux.Si les paso lo mismo que yo me podrian ayudar con eso.

Comment: que error te aparase? que sale si intentas buscarlo? como lo estas instalando? algo que pueda proveer alguna informacion mas alla de solo adivinar!

Comment: @Bryro pues no me sale ningun error solo doy clic a megasync y no me aparece ningun mensaje.

Comment: Deberías ser más específico en los pasos que seguiste para instalar la app o, al menos, proporcionar un enlace a las instrucciones. Por otra parte, creo que sería mejor instalar desde [AUR](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages?O=0&K=megasync), hay varias opciones. Sugiero `megasync-bin` para instalar binarios en vez de compilar en tu equipo.

Comment: @Triby Gracias si me funciono asi.